# Java, Regular Expression HasNext starts with empty line, multi-platform support

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I need to process the following file on Unix and Windows:

```
a;b
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g

a;b
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g

a;b

a;b
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g
c;d;e;f;g
```

i need to process `a;b` that contain a block of data underneath.
e.g. the *third* `a;b` shouldn't be processed.

currently i am delimiting by using the following regular expression this type of text in a file using Java scanner:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        try{

            fileScanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^$", Pattern.MULTILINE));

            while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
                String line;
                while ((line = fileScanner.nextLine()).isEmpty());
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileScanner.next().getBytes("UTF-8"));
...
```

This will still delegate for the *third* `a;b` the empty input into the ByteArrayInputStream.

Hoe may i check if the first line of `fileScanner.next()` is an empty line and then execute nextLine() statement and a following a continue statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?m)^(?:.+(?:\\r?\\n|\\Z)){2,}
```

which matches two or more non-empty lines, or other words two or more `(?:...){2,}` lines that contain one or more characters `.+` followed by new line `\\r?\\n` or `(?:...|...)` end of string `\\Z`.

Multiline modifier `(?m)` means that `^` matches a beginning of each line, not just the beginning of the string.

---

#### Demo:

```
String str = "...";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(?:.+(?:\\r?\\n|\\Z)){2,}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println(match);
}
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/Wegwpc)**.