# Java, Scanning large file, findWithinHorizon(p, 0) throws exception java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex, exception, java.util.scanner

The Following is a snapshot of my code , the input file is of size 45 Mb

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
String scannedFarm;
try{

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:.+(?:\\r?\\n|\\Z)){2,}",Pattern.MULTILINE);

    while((scannedFarm = fileScanner.findWithinHorizon(p, 0)) != null){ // Throws Exception
    ...
    ...
```

I'll add any additional info that may clarify why the exception is thrown.
Related question which describes the file format may help: [Java, Regular Expression HasNext starts with empty line, multi-platform support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232689/java-regular-expression-hasnext-starts-with-empty-line-multi-platform-support).

BTW: This works on small files like a charm, on larger it fails , does a String has maximum size returned from findWithinHorizon?

**UPDATE**

As was requested a small stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/dcJ1jdkf

And a small example of the file snapshot:

http://pastebin.com/EYMsbrKj

Comment: Post stacktrace, please. Don't you?

Comment: Stackoverflow is the right place to ask about a stack overflow! Sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the workings of the `Scanner` class, but whatever `.findwithinHorizon()` does with the regex, that regex is extremely strange.

This regex will match the entire file at once, as long as each line is at least one character long. If there are empty lines, then it will match all blocks in-between empty lines that span at least two lines. If that's what you actually intend to do, there's a much better way of doing that:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^.+$(?:\\r?\\n)?){2,}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

In order to avoid unnecessary backtracking of the regex engine, you could make all the quantifiers [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^.++$(?:\\r?+\\n)?+){2,}+", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

With or without possessive quantifiers, this regex matches as follows:

[image: Screenshot RegexBuddy]

Comment: Works as a charm without Exceptions , Great thanks, you are a big /huge helper, hope it will not fail on a larger files , i have tried 300 MG files and it works, although the JVM memory usage is very high -> about 1.5 G , if i could vote several time up, i would!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have an easier time of it matching the tokens themselves rather than the delimiters.  That's really what the `findWithinHorizon()` method is for: an alternative to Scanner's preferred operating mode, as represented by the `hasNextXXX()` and `nextXXX()` methods.

```
"(?m)^\\w+;\\w+$(?:\r?\n\\w+(?:;\\w+)+$)+"
```

You haven't given a detailed description of your data format, so I just used the simplest regex that would match your sample.

Comment: This expression doesn't fit to my needs,  i did attach a link to the related question which describes the format.